# How to start multiple intent by package name

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity

I want start multiple app at the same time

so I use this

```
            startActivity(getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.android.chrome"));
            startActivity(getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.android.settings"));
```

I tried many packages, the default android app or the app from google play

only the last app can be started. How to modify the program to start multiple intent?

Comment: You only have 1 foreground app.  So starting two activities right after each other is going to cause the second one to come up.  What are you trying to do here?

Comment: Give a delay between both the calls and try. And obviously your last call will be in forefront screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, check [startActivities()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#startActivities%28android.content.Intent[],%20android.os.Bundle%29) method. 
As following documentation snippet states: 
*Note that unlike that approach, generally none of the activities except the last in the array will be created at this point, but rather will be created when the user first visits them (due to pressing back from the activity on top).*

That is, multiple apps can be started via intents but each next Activity overlays the previous one.

**Update** 
Try following code:

```
public void launchActivities(View v) {
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

    Intent startChrome = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.android.chrome");
    PendingIntent pi1 = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 666, startChrome, 0);
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC, System.currentTimeMillis() + 500, pi1);

    Intent startSettings = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.android.settings");
    PendingIntent pi2 = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 667, startSettings, 0);
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC, System.currentTimeMillis() + 1000, pi2);

    finish();
}
```

Change `System.currentTimeMillis() + N` parameter to set the appropriate time between launches.

Comment: That is not completely true, after you tap the back button, the previous one will be started, but the previous one will only be started after you tap the back button. You can try this, 1.run the two startActivity. 2.tap the recent apps button, now you can see the last app only. 3.select the started app. 4.tap the back button. then the result is that the previous one will not be started. While I want all app will be actually started after run the program.